# How to click mouse button rapidly when key is held down

Tags: python, pywin32, pynput

how do I trigger the mouse being clicked rapidly when a key is held down (shift key in this instance). My code is currently

```
import win32api                               
import win32con                               
import time                                   
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller   
mouse = Controller()                          
while True:                                  
    keystate = win32api.GetAsyncKeyState(0x10)                          
    if keystate < 0:                          
        mouse.click(Button.left, 2)                         
    else:                                     
        pass
```

The issue I'm having is everytime I actually press the shift key the program crashes. When printing out the keystate it shows 0 until shift is pressed in which it shows -32767 and then it stops printing and I have to kill the process. How do I stop this from happening.

Comment: maybe you should use `pynput.mouse.Listener` to catch when `shift` it pressed ?

Comment: program runs very fast and it can check keys very many times in one second - so it may click button very many times in one second and it can make problem. You may have to use some variables to control if button was pressed only once.

Comment: code `else: pass` is useless - you can remove it.

Comment: you may also try to use second variable which remeber `previous_keystate` and click button only when `previous_keystate` is `0` - and at the end of loop always use `previous_keystate = keystate`. This way it should click button only once when you press shift and when you keep it pressed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Windows but Linux so I can't check it but program runs very fast and it runs loop a lot of times in one second, and it checks `shift` a lot of times in one second, and it click button a lot of times in one second, and this may make problem.

You can use second variable to remeber `previous_keystate` and click button only when `previous_keystate == 0`

```
import win32api                               
import win32con                               
import time                                   
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller, Listener

mouse = Controller()

previous_keystate = 0

while True:                                  
    keystate = win32api.GetAsyncKeyState(0x10)  
                        
    if previous_keystate == 0 and keystate < 0:                          
        mouse.click(Button.left, 2)

    previous_keystate = keystate
```

---

**BTW:** as I rember in documentation you can find information that `click(Button.left, 2)` may not work on some systems.

---

I would use `pynput.keyboard.Listener` to get pressed key - it execute function only once when key is pressed (and not repeate function when key is keep pressed). And it works also on Linux.

```
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

# --- functions ---

def on_press(key):
    #print(key)
    
    if key == Key.shift:
        mouse.click(Button.left, 2)
        
    # to stop on ESC    
    if key == Key.esc:
        return False

# --- main ---
            
mouse = Controller()

with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    # ... some code ...
    listener.join()
```

or

```
# --- main ---
            
mouse = Controller()

listener = Listener(on_press=on_press)
listener.start()
# ... some code ...
listener.join()
```